# IN EXCEL, how do you add 2 columns then blank one of the columns without effecting the balance?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel

inventory # EX col A  -10
                    B   25 currently

Question: If col A changes next month to -5, how can you blank out A-10, replace it with A-5, without effecting B.

```
                A - 5
                B  20
```

Next month          A + 30
                    b   50

Comment: We need more information, I can't make any sense out of what your excel sheet needs or how it's currently formatted.

Comment: I'd agree with more information request.  My initial reading of it would be that cell B1 is a running total basically.  I think the only way to do this would be to use a vba on change event with the B1 taking the value of B1+A1.  I think this is a very dangerous way to do this due to not having a way to follow the progression of B1 value

Answer (score 0):

This is not how Excel works. Cells have either a formula or a constant value. Cells with formulas will re-calculate. References to other cells will update cells with formulas and there is no history of previously entered values. Excel can only calculate with the values that are currently in the cells.

In a monthly register like the one that (I think) you describe, you would normally add the next months data in a new row and then use calculations that add/subtract the current month's value from the previous month's value. Consider this:

[image]

The formula in cell C3 is `=C2+B3` and has been copied down to row 5. Each month, add a new row with date and stock movement. Then copy the formula down.